# convert empty array to null pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark Dataframe:

Dataframe example:

```
id |  column_1       | column_2    | column_3
--------------------------------------------
1  |    ["12"]       |   ["""]     |    ["67"]
--------------------------------------------
2  |    ["""]        |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
3  |    ["""]        |  ["93"]     |   ["56"]
--------------------------------------------
4  |    ["100"]      |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to convert all the values `["""]` of the columns: `column_1, column_2, column_3` `to null`. types of these 3 columns is an `Array`.

Excpect result:

```
id |  column_1       | column_2    | column_3
--------------------------------------------
1  |    ["12"]       |   null     |    ["67"]
--------------------------------------------
2  |    null        |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
3  |    null        |  ["93"]     |   ["56"]
--------------------------------------------
4  |    ["100"]      |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
```

I tried this solution bellow:

```
df = df.withColumn(
        "column_1",
        F.when((F.size(F.col("column_1")) == ""),
        F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col("column_1"))
    ).withColumn(
        "column_2",
        F.when((F.size(F.col("column_2")) == ""),
        F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col("column_2"))
    ).withColumn(
        "column_3",
        F.when((F.size(F.col("column_3")) == ""),
        F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col("column_3"))
    )
```

But it convert all to null.
How can I test on an empty array that contain an empty String normally, [""] not [].
Thank you

Comment: arrays contain always just 1 value ?

Comment: sometimes contain more one value. but I put just an example

Comment: @Steven I tested in my code also using column > 0, but it changed all to null

Comment: which version of spark ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can test with a `when` and replace the values:

```py
df.withColumn(
    "column_1", 
    F.when(F.col("column_1") != F.array(F.lit('"')),  # or '"""' ?
    F.col("column_1")
))
```

Do that for each of your columns.