# Filter if String contain sub-string pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 datasets. In each one I have several columns. But I want to use `only 2 columns from each dataset, without doing any join, merge or combination between the both of the datasets.`

Example dataset 1:

```
column_dataset_1 <String>    |      column_dataset_1_normalized <String>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
11882621-V021BRP161305-1     |      11882621V021BRP1613051
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
W-B.7120RP1605794            |      WB7120RP1605794
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
D/57RP.1534421               |      D57RP1534421
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
125858G_022BR/P070751        |      125858G022BRP070751
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
300B.5190C57/51507           |      300B5190C5751507
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example dataset 2

```
column_dataset_2 <String>                                                           |       column_dataset_2_normalized <String>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Por ejemplo, si W-B.7120RP1605794se trata de un archivo de texto,                   |  PorejemplosiWB7120RP1605794setratadeunarchivodetexto 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
se abrirá en un programa de procesamiento de texto.                                 |  seabrirenunprogramadeprocesamientodetexto
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
utilizados 125858G_022BR/P070751 frecuentemente (por ejemplo, un texto que describe |  utilizados125858G022BRP070751frecuentementeporejemplountextoquedescribe

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

column_dataset_1_normalized is the result of column_dataset_1 is normalized
column_dataset_2_normalized is the resut of column_dataset_2 is normalized

I want to compare `column_dataset_1_normalized` if is exist in `column_dataset_2_normalized`.
If yes I should `extract it from column_dataset_2`

Example:

`WB7120RP1605794` is in the `second line` of `column_dataset_1_normalized`, is exist in the `first line of column_dataset_2_normalized`, so I should `extract` it's `real value [W-B.7120RP1605794]`, from `column_dataset_2` and store it in a new column in dataset 2.

And the same for `125858G022BRP070751` is `in forth line in column_dataset_2_normalized`, I should `extract it from column_dataset_2 [125858G_022BR/P070751]`.
The comparaison should, take one by one value of `column_dataset_1_normalized` and search it in `all the cell of column_dataset_2_normalized`.

For normalization I used this code to kepp only number and letter:

```
df = df.withColumn(
        "column_normalized",
        F.regexp_replace(F.col("column_to_normalize"), "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ""))
```

Someone can propose me a suggestion how can I do it ?
Thank you

Comment: And why don't you want to do this with a join? It's the canonical answer to the problem you're describing. Can you elaborate on what you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: @OliverW. Thanks for your answer. I don't have a common columns between the datasets. For this reason I asked the question. I'm trying to find a solution on my side.  hopeful I find a suggestion / help from you.

Comment: `df1.join(df2, expr('column_dataset_2_normalized rlike column_dataset_1_normalized')).select('column_dataset_1')`

Comment: @verojoucla, you don't need a common column when join two dataframes. you can also use function `instr(...) > 0`  in the join condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various way to join two dataframes:

(1) find the location/position of string *column_dataset_1_normalized* in *column_dataset_2_normalized* by using SQL function [locate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#locate), [instr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#instr), [position](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#position)  etc, return a position (1-based) if exists

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

    cond1 = expr('locate(column_dataset_1_normalized,column_dataset_2_normalized)>0')
    cond2 = expr('instr(column_dataset_2_normalized,column_dataset_1_normalized)>0')
    cond3 = expr('position(column_dataset_1_normalized IN column_dataset_2_normalized)>0')
```

(2) use regex [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rlike) to find *column_dataset_1_normalized* from *column_dataset_2_normalized*, this is only valid when no regex meta-characters is shown in *column_dataset_1_normalized*

```
    cond4 = expr('column_dataset_2_normalized rlike column_dataset_1_normalized')
```

Run the following code and use one of the above conditions, for example:

```
df1.join(df2, cond1).select('column_dataset_1').show(truncate=False)
+---------------------+
|column_dataset_1     |
+---------------------+
|W-B.7120RP1605794    |
|125858G_022BR/P070751|
+---------------------+
```

**Edit:** Per comments, the matched sub-string might not be the same as *df1.column_dataset_1*, so we will need to reverse-engineer the sub-string from the normalized string. Based on how the normalization is conducted, the following udf might help (notice this will not cover any leading/trailing non-alnum that might be in the matched). Basically, we will iterate through the string by chars and find the start/end index of the normalized string in the original string, then take the sub-string:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf('string')
def find_matched(orig, normalized):
  n, d = ([], [])
  for i in range(len(orig)):
    if orig[i].isalnum(): 
      n.append(orig[i])
      d.append(i)
  idx = ''.join(n).find(normalized)
  return orig[d[idx]:d[idx+len(normalized)]] if idx >= 0 else None

df1.join(df2, cond3) \
   .withColumn('matched', find_matched('column_dataset_2', 'column_dataset_1_normalized')) \
   .select('column_dataset_2', 'matched', 'column_dataset_1_normalized') \
   .show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|column_dataset_2                                                                    |matched                |column_dataset_1_normalized|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|Por ejemplo, si W-B.7120RP-1605794se trata de un archivo de texto,                  |W-B.7120RP-1605794     |WB7120RP1605794            |
|utilizados 125858G_022BR/P-070751 frecuentemente (por ejemplo, un texto que describe|125858G_022BR/P-070751 |125858G022BRP070751        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test it. But I would like to extrcat the value of the reference from column_dataset_2, because sometime the column_dataset_2 and column_dataset_1 are differents.

Comment: @verojoucla, just add `column_dataset_2` into the select method, is that what you need? `df.join(...).select('column_dataset_1', 'column_dataset_2')`

Comment: I should take one by one from column_dataset_1_normalized, I search it in all column_dataset_2_normalized column.
If I find it, I extract it from column_dataset_2. 

I already put an example about (WB7120RP1605794) in my question.

Comment: I hope that you understood my need. Thank you

Comment: you meant the sub-string you are looking for in column_dataset_2 might be different from column_dataset_1 even if the normalized strings match? If that's the case, I will have to know how you normalize these string.

Comment: I edited my question, I added a code how I normalized the columns.
About your question, if the sub-string that I'm looking for in column_dataset_2 might be different or no from column_dataset_1 even if the normalized strings match. Some times are mathed some times no.

Comment: what I did so far, I found the column_dataset_2_normalized that exist in column_dataset_1_normalized. I joined the two datasets and I created a dataframe that contain the 4 columns. Now, I should extract the column_dataset_1_normalized from column_dataset_2, I mean extract it's value without normalization.
I already used your solution "cond3"

Comment: this might require a udf and will not be able to cover the leading and trailing non-alnum if exists.

Comment: ok let's try please, can you suggest me a solution, thank you very much

Comment: BTW. for testing purpose, I added some non-alnum chars into your original example texts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me why I got this error, it concern the withcolumn step: Some Error messages:  
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6207.withColumn. : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: functionExists is not supported 

Thank you very much

Comment: this is most likely from your spark version. I only tested it on spark 2.4. older version might not support the spark.udf.register syntax. I can revert this back to the previous version of the post.

Comment: I tried to change the udf using:
 udf_matched = udf(find_matched, 'string')
 Then I used udf_matched function in withColumn, but it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203530/discussion-between-jxc-and-verojoucla).

Comment: I'm very sorry, but really I very need to your help please. Can you help me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228817/extract-string-from-text-pyspark
have a nice weekend and thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: @verojoucla, I think you already had an answer there. have a good weekend.

Comment: I know that I disturbed you, I'm sorry, but really I didn't find a solution for the issue of the performance when I use a big data. The proposed solution, doesn't work because the build took more than 5 hours and still running. I'm really need to your experience. Thanks a lot. I'm  still talking about the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228817/extract-string-from-text-pyspark/59229857?noredirect=1#comment104710107_59229857

Comment: @verojoucla, there is nothing too much we can do in the SQL end. probably have to find the bottleneck and tune the cluster configuration.

Comment: Hi, @jxc :)
Can you give a suggestion about my question please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931770/sum-of-column-values-pyspark

Thanks

Comment: @verojoucla, added an answer, as I remember your Spark version is below 2.4, so you might need to use explode or udf solution.

Comment: Hi @jxc I know that I disturbed you more, I'm sorry. I trust only on you.
Can you please give a suggestion about my question and take your time until tomorrow, I will accept only your solution. Thank you very much
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190375/compare-two-datasets-in-pyspark

Comment: Hi, @verojoucla, I am not online as often as I did last year due to my schedules. but I believe you can get enough help from the community anyway:)