# Extract String from text pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe:

Example:

```
text <String>                 |   name <String>  |   original_name <String>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HELLOWORLD2019THISISGOOGLE    |   WORLD2019      |   WORLD_2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
NATUREISVERYGOODFORHEALTH     |   null           |   null  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
THESUNCONTAINVITAMIND         |   VITAMIND       |   VITAMIN_D
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
BECARETOOURHEALTHISVITAMIND   |   OURHEALTH      |   OUR_/HEALTH
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to loop the `name` column and look if `name` values exists in `text`, if yes, I create a `new_column`, will be contain the `original_name` value of the `name` values found in `text`. Knowing that some times the dataframe columns are `null`.

Example:

- in the line 4 in the dataframe example, the `text` contain 2 values from `name` column: `[OURHEALTH, VITAMIND]`, I should take its `original_name` values and store them in a `new_column`.
- in the line 2, the `text` contain `OURHEALTH` from `name` column, I should store in the `new_column` the original `name` value that found ==> `[OUR_/HEALTH]`

Expect result:

```
text <String>                 |   name <String>  |   original_name <String>  | new_column <Array>
------------------------------|------------------|---------------------------|----------------------------
HELLOWORLD2019THISISGOOGLE    |   WORLD2019      |   WORLD_2019              |  [WORLD_2019]
------------------------------|------------------|---------------------------|----------------------------
NATUREISVERYGOODFOROURHEALTH  |   null           |   null                    |  [OUR_/HEALTH]
------------------------------|------------------|---------------------------|----------------------------
THESUNCONTAINVITAMIND         |   VITAMIND       |   VITAMIN_D               |  [VITAMIN_D]
------------------------------|------------------|---------------------------|----------------------------
BECARETOOURHEALTHISVITAMIND   |   OURHEALTH      |   OUR_/HEALTH             |  [OUR_/HEALTH, VITAMIN_D ]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------
```

I hope that I was clear in my explanation.

I tried by the following code:

```
df = df.select("text", "name", "original_name").agg(collect_set("name").alias("name_array"))
for name_item in name_array:    
    df.withColumn("new_column", F.when(df.text.contains(name_item), "original_name").otherwise(None))
```

Someone can help me please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to use `join` between the original DataFrame and a derived DataFrame with just the `name` column. As the join condition could be satisfied by multiple rows, we'll have to groupby the original column after join.

Here is a detailed example for your input :

```
data = [
    ("HELLOWORLD2019THISISGOOGLE", "WORLD2019", "WORLD_2019"),
    ("NATUREISVERYGOODFOROURHEALTH", None, None),
    ("THESUNCONTAINVITAMIND", "VITAMIND", "VITAMIN_D"),
    ("BECARETOOURHEALTHISVITAMIND", "OURHEALTH", "OUR_ / HEALTH")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["text", "name", "original_name"])

# create new DF with search words
# as it's the originl_name which interests us for the final list so we select it too
search_df = df.select(struct(col("name"), col("original_name")).alias("search_match"))

# join on df.text contains search_df.name
df_join = df.join(search_df, df.text.contains(search_df["search_match.name"]), "left")

# group by original columns and collect matches in a list
df_join.groupBy("text", "name", "original_name")\
    .agg(collect_list(col("search_match.original_name")).alias("new_column"))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------------+
|text                        |name     |original_name|new_column                |
+----------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------------+
|HELLOWORLD2019THISISGOOGLE  |WORLD2019|WORLD_2019   |[WORLD_2019]              |
|THESUNCONTAINVITAMIND       |VITAMIND |VITAMIN_D    |[VITAMIN_D]               |
|NATUREISVERYGOODFOROURHEALTH|null     |null         |[OUR_ / HEALTH]           |
|BECARETOOURHEALTHISVITAMIND |OURHEALTH|OUR_ / HEALTH|[VITAMIN_D, OUR_ / HEALTH]|
+----------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it seems work well in your example. In fact, I'm testing it, are you sure that work on big data ? Because the build blocked in the first join. it run with no finish.

Comment: What do you mean by "_it run with no finish_"? sure that when you join dataframe on condition "_string contains another string_" it will be not performant but the logic is correct and should not block. Did you look into spark job history to see what's going on?

Comment: I mean that the build is still running since more 1 hour. I exterminated the jobs status, I have somes tasks are finished with succeeded, and some tasks there status change from time to time, from running to expired, then go back to running.

Comment: If you have large DataFrame, you need to do some optimizations because joining on string LIKE is never performant. Maybe you can try to broadcast the dataframe with keywords to seach or persist/cache it before join... see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938672/efficient-string-matching-in-apache-spark).

Comment: DO you know please if there's a difference between these two joins bellow:
Test_1 ==> df_join = df1.join(F.broadcast(df2), df1.String.contains(df2["search.subString"]), "left") 

The running go fast, as job status, but the job took 2 hours and did not finish.

Test_2 ==> df_join = F.broadcast(df1).join(F.broadcast(df2), df1.String.contains(df2["search.subString"]), "left")

The running is very slow, the job still running since 2 hours also and did not finish. Thank you in advance.