# Check if array contain an array

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset:

```
number  |  matricule<array>   | name<array>  |    model <array>
----------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  []                 |  [7]         |     [7]
----------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  [9]                |  [4]         |     [9]
----------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  [8]                |  [2]         |     [8, 2]
----------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  [2]                |  [3, 4]      |     [3,4]
```

I would like to add a new column "Falg" that contain true or false according the comparison result.

Comparison rule:

```
if model column contain all values of name columns and not contain matricule array ==> Flag = True
else false.

In case if model contain matricule and contain name (like in line 3 in the dataframe example) ==> Flag = False.
```

I tried by this code bellow:

```
def is_subset(a, b):
        if F.size(F.array_except(a, b)) == 0:
            return "True"
        else:
            return "False"
    validate = F.udf(is_subset)
    df_join = df_join.withColumn("Flag", validate(F.col("name"), F.col("model")))
    return df_join

I got an error:


Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
in is_subset
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

I tried by this code:

```
df_join = df_join.withColumn("Flag", F.when(
            ((F.size(F.expr(F.array_except(F.col("name"), F.col("model"))) == F.lit(0))) 
            & (F.size(F.expr(F.array_except(F.col("matricule"), F.col("model"))) != F.lit(0)))) , True
            ).otherwise(False))
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable in this line ((F.size(F.expr(F.array_except(F.col("name"), F.col("model"))) == F.lit(0)))
```

Expected result:

```
number  |  matricule<array>   | name<array>  |    model <array>   | Flag
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  []                 |  [7]         |     [7]            |   True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  [9]                |  [4]         |     [9]            |   False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  [8]                |  [2]         |     [8, 2]         |   False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AA      |  [2]                |  [3, 4]      |     [3,4]          |  True
```

Someone please can suggest me a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: you can use sql functions to compare arrays:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: I think array_except is not accepted

Comment: you could also try to adapt the udf mentioned in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708014/array-intersection-in-spark-sql

Comment: @mrjoseph thanks for your answer. How can I do it using an udf please.

Comment: @verojoucla i dont think there is a need for udf, and it is inefficient. try my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If you dont want to preserve duplicates:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("nm", F.array_intersect("name","model"))\
  .withColumn("nm1", F.array_intersect("matriculate","model"))\
  .withColumn("flag2", F.when((F.col("nm1")==F.col("matriculate"))&(F.size("matriculate")!=0),F.lit(False)).otherwise(F.lit(True)))\
  .withColumn("Flag", F.when((F.col("flag2")==F.lit(True))&(F.col("nm")!=F.col("name")), F.lit(False)).otherwise(F.col("flag2")))\
  .drop("nm","nm1","flag2").show()

+------+-----------+------+------+-----+
|number|matriculate|  name| model| Flag|
+------+-----------+------+------+-----+
|    AA|         []|   [7]|   [7]| true|
|    AA|        [9]|   [4]|   [9]|false|
|    AA|        [8]|   [2]|[8, 2]|false|
|    AA|        [2]|[3, 4]|[3, 4]| true|
+------+-----------+------+------+-----+
```

## If you want to preserve duplicates:

Have to use udf here as array_intersect does not preserve duplicates

```
def intersect(ar1,ar2):
     return [i for i in ar1 if i in ar2]

udf1= F.udf(intersect, ArrayType(LongType()))

df.withColumn("nm", udf1("name","model"))\
      .withColumn("nm1", udf1("matriculate","model"))\
      .withColumn("flag2", F.when((F.col("nm1")==F.col("matriculate"))&(F.size("matriculate")!=0),F.lit(False)).otherwise(F.lit(True)))\
      .withColumn("Flag", F.when((F.col("flag2")==F.lit(True))&(F.col("nm")!=F.col("name")), F.lit(False)).otherwise(F.col("flag2")))\
      .drop("nm","nm1","flag2").show()


+------+-----------+------+------+-----+
|number|matriculate|  name| model| Flag|
+------+-----------+------+------+-----+
|    AA|         []|   [7]|   [7]| true|
|    AA|        [9]|   [4]|   [9]|false|
|    AA|        [8]|   [2]|[8, 2]|false|
|    AA|        [2]|[3, 4]|[3, 4]| true|
+------+-----------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: I come back to you after a deep testing. I'm sorry but this logic is not good, especially when you used array_intersect function, we loss some data from name and matricule.

Comment: array_intersect returns an intersection of elements, without duplicates. you are only losing duplicates, and i thought that would not be an issue as you did not have any in your question

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes but I'm looking the existence of an array in an array, and an array is not an array. of course when I say an array I mean every element in the Array A for example should exist in array B to return True. And for the second array "matricule" if only one element exist in array model even if all elements of name array exist in model, I should return false.

Comment: i have updated answer with udf instead of array_intersect to preserve duplicates if that was the only hole in my logic. im a little confused about what you mean by 'existence of an array in an array, and an array is not an array'